# Slide event in Jquery/JS for mobile template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I marked up an template using HTML for mobile devices.

It contents left menu, that is appeared after click. 
How can I hide this menu when I slide display from right to left?
What is method in JS/Jquery can I use?

Comment: Is this what you want? [jQuery Mobile - Open panel on swipe](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-swipe-open/#demo-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using jQuery's "swipe" and "touchstart" events like this:

```
function swipe(){
  $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('slideout');
}
$('body').on( "swiperight", swipe());
$('body').on( "swipeleft", swipe());

//or simply
$('body').on( "swipe", swipe());
```

You'll need to create the class in your CSS that will have the correct styles that will display and hide your menu.